# Shiny - runcodeUI - How to access the code entered in runcodeUI as if it was a simple textInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to produce a Shiny app. I use a runcodeUI()+runcodeServer() with useShinyjs() to let the user enter a Rcode. Then, I would like to send back that r code entered by the user as an output, as if runcodeUI was a textInput. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runcodeUI` actually creates a `textInput` (or `textAreaInput` etc). Its name is `runcode_exp`, and you can access it in the regular way:

`input$runcode_expr`

Do not that this identifier could potentially change in the future (if you use it in many places, you may want to wrap it in a reactive so that it's easy to change later), and of course that `runcodeServer` is an `eval`, and therefore a huge security risk.